# jquery submit not working

Tags: jquery, submit

I cant get this form to submit correctly. If I have the button type as "submit" it always submits and if I use "button" as the type it never submits, the ajax call brings in the correct values, so even though the `if` statement follows the correct path but it doesnt seem to matter.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("#submitButton").click(function(e) {
        var un  = $('#username').val();
        $('#mike').html("");       
            $.ajax(
            {              
                type: "POST",
                url: "Utilities/CheckUsername.php",
                data: "un="+ un,
                success: function(data2)
                {                  
                   if(data2=="Username Does Not Exist")
                    {         
                       $("#login2").submit();                   
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $('#mike').html(data2);
                        return false;                      
                    }                   
                }

            });
             });

             }); 
             </script>
</head>
<body>
      <form name="login" id="login2" method="post" action="dsds.html">
        UserName<input type="text" name="username" id="username"value="">
        <br/>
        Password<input type="text" name="password" id="password" value="">
        <br/>
        Password Again<input type="text" name="passwordagain" id="passwordagain" value="">
        <br/>
        <input type="hidden" name="NewClass" id="NewClass" value="true">
        <br/>
        <input type="submit" name="no" id="submitButton" value="submit">
     </form>
     <span id = "mike"></span>
</body>
</html>
```

EDIT:
I added the return false here and it works, but why? I am just returning false from the click event

```
else
            {
                $('#mike').html(data2);

            }                   
        }

    });
     return false;
     });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to `return false` from your submit event handler. The `return false` you have in there isn't performed until *after* the asynch ajax call is finished.

Alternatively you can use `e.preventDefault()` which does the same thing.

Both methods simply prevent the default behavior, i.e. submitting the form, from occurring.

Comment: Solved my problem. The complaint was that the $.post(..) file was undefined.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you bind the event handler to the `submit` event of the form:

```
$('#login2').submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    //...
});
```

You have to prevent the default action for the event, which is submitting the form. This is done with [`event.preventDefault` *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/). The `return false` inside the Ajax callback will have no effect, as the event handler returns *before* the response was received.

If you do this, you have to set some kind of flag to see in which state of the process you are:

```
var nameAvailable = false;

$('#login2').submit(function(event) {
    if(!nameAvailable) {
        event.preventDefault(); // don't submit form
        //...
        $.ajax({
            success: function() {
                // if name available
                nameAvailable = true;
                $('#login2').submit();
            }
        });
     }
});
```